# Typecast char as NSInteger

Tags: objective-c

I googled a bit on this topic but I couldn't really find anything helpful. Here's the code that I'm confused about:

```
const char *beginning = "Love";
NSLog(@"%s", beginning); //Love
NSLog(@"%d", (NSInteger)beginning); //14687
```

What does `(NSInteger)beginning` mean? Why does it output 14687?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not really trying to "do" anything. Just playing around with the code haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not casting a char to NSInteger, you are casting a pointer to a character array to an NSInteger.
The value is the value of the pointer to that character array.

See this link for tutorials on pointers and arrays in C

http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm

Comment: The value is the "value" of the pointer to that character array? What does that mean? Do you mean the value is the "memory cell" of the pointer to that character array?

Comment: A pointer is the value of an address of a memory location. - yes! kind of, your getting there.